# Required fields check logic of Lightning Web Component open source

Tags: lightning-web-components, open-source

In Aura or LWC, `lightning:inputField`and`lightning-inputField` inherits

salesforce's check logic about required field.

How about in LWC-open source?

We cannot use pre-built components, so must use basic html tag.

If I can use salesforce checklogic in LWC-open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They say you can use HTML 5](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation)
Below is some Javascript from the docs, to access the api:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    register(event) {
        var inputCmp = this.template.querySelector(".inputCmp");
        var value = inputCmp.value;
        // is input valid text?
        if (value === "John Doe") {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("John Doe is already registered");
        } else {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity(""); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity(); // Tells lightning-input to show the error right away without needing interaction
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean salesforce API contains its check logic?

Comment: I think it's just HTML 5 and javascript, not necessarily salesforce if I'm understanding the question correctly. As soon as your handler is invoked, you can query for the component and add the message you want. I've tried it and it seems to work with a variety of inputs, in your case an input file.

Comment: I mean if I can use "validation rules" of custom objects from LWC-opensource, out of Salesforce platform.

Comment: You can use the framework to create your own components and add regex / logic to validate your inputs using the [Custom Validity Error Messages
The component supports setCustomValidity() from HTML5's Constraint Validation API. To set an error message, provide a quoted string to display.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation)See details at https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-setcustomvalidity.